# Using "Find a Manager" action in SP Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have created a 2010 list workflow using the following actions:

> Find Manager of (Current Item: Reviewer 1) (output to (Variable: manager))
>   If (Variable: manager is (not empty)
>   Update item in (Current Item)

I published this workflow and went into my SP 2013 list workflow and did the following:

> Start a List Workflow with (no parameters) on (Current Item)
>   Go to (End of Workflow)

Both workflows are set to start automatically with a new item.
I tested by adding a new item to the list. I can see that both workflows were successfully completed, but there is nothing that appears in the Manager column that I assigned the workflow to update.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I found this article that was of great help to me:
[Lookup Manager of a User](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27785543/Lookup-Manager-of-a-User-SharePoint-designer-2010-workflow.html)

In the 2010 workflow, Find Manager action, for the user you are looking at, make sure to set the "Return Field as" dropdown to "Login Name".

This fix, along with my steps above seemed to work.